# Append to URI/URL live without refreshing the page location with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, url-rewriting, url-routing

What I have is a MVC framework that I am manipulating the DOM via JavaScript and jQuery. Which to a point is a mute reference to this question. Through the MVC if I go to

domain.com/page/

I land on a default page with recent info, updates, etc. However through the MVC if I go to something like

domain.com/page/ref1/ref2/ref3

We can handle that on the backend to do what we want. When its gone to directly. So the thought here for this question is, can I mimic the behavior cross browser up to at least up to IE 6/7+, Firefox 3.x+, Chrome. And by mimic I mean manipulate the URL/URI like I would the DOM itself. This way when someone comes along and navigates to sections via the methods we manipulate the DOM and find something they want to share all they have to do is go up to the browsers URL bar, and then copy and paste it to a message.

What would be even nicer is a method that can work with the back and forth history buttons on browsers as well. All without having to reload/refresh the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried

```
window.location.replace(URL)
```

This function doesn't load any pages.If you change your current location like this , when you redirect to somewhere , your last address will be the non-modified address.It doesnt write new URL to the browser history.So it would be like as if you just give the key to what the user wants to share.

Comment: This is a good starting point. Thank you. Is there anyway that's cross browser compatible to invoke the use of the back button? Or is that to much to hope for? I found a couple things but they really dont work to well.

Comment: have you tried `history.back()` ? takes you to last point in the browser history. this is a java script code.i guess it must be cross-browser compatible as W3 says so http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered modifying the anchors in the URL?  While on this page:

http://www.google.com/

Changing the URL to this:

http://www.google.com/#foo

... won't trigger a page refresh.  So you could use (read/modify) the contents of the URL after the anchor all you want and the page won't get reloaded.  Should be able to build on that idea.

Comment: I have concidered doing it with anchors, and have in the past with some projects however the current requirement from the people running the project is they don't want to see the # in the URL they want it all / all the way down the URL. I wish it was easy as that hash though cause then I'd use # to break it, and then anything after # could be split by / I am unfortunately not that lucky at the movement.